# How to echo PHP array in a format

Tags: php

Is there a way I can echo an array of value in this format`[200,135,667,333,526,996,564,123,890,464,655]` I have my PHP code as below:

```
$sql_sum_up = "SELECT * FROM `payment`";
$result_sum_up = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_sum_up);
$count_sum_up = mysqli_num_rows($result_sum_up); 
      
while($row_sum_up = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sum_up,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $price = $row_sum_up['price'];
}
```

I want when I echo `$price` it should come in this format `[200,135,667,333,526,996,564,123,890,464,655]`

Comment: You want `$price` to be an array and add values into the array, instead of overwriting it…?!

Comment: json_encode it?!

Comment: You have errors in your query: `ordered by DESC` should be `order by [column-name] DESC`

Comment: Create an array, add each row price to it, then echo it at the end of the loop. Or in PDO use `fetchAll()` (I'm not sure what the mysqli equivalent is) and lose the loop completely.

Comment: @droopsnoot - In mysqli, you can use [mysqli_fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). But then they should also add `SELECT price FROM ...` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start of by indenting your code correctly. There's almost always a function for auto-formatting in most editors, such as *Visual Studio Code*, *NetBeans*, etc. Or use [an online tool](https://codebeautify.org/php-beautifier) to do it.
- Correct your SQL query since there's no point getting all values if you just read the `price` value and you are ordering without mentionning the field name:

  ```sql
  SELECT `price` FROM `payment` ORDER BY `field_name` DESC
  ```
- Create an array variable which you will fill with the prices:

  ```php
  $prices = [];
  ```
- In your loop reading the database values, fill the array:

  ```php
  $prices[] = $row_sum_up['price'];
  ```

  Alternatively, you could also fetch all values instead of looping. By the way, it's best to use [PHP's PDO abstraction layer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of *mysqli_()* functions.
- After the loop, export it to JSON:

  ```php
  print json_encode($prices);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as someone already mentioned in the comments you have an error in your SQL synthax. The correct ORDER BY synthax is "ORDER BY [field-name] DESC"

You could achieve what you want in different ways.

First of all you want to create an array that contains all prices:

```
$sql_sum_up = "SELECT * FROM `payment`";
$result_sum_up = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_sum_up);
$count_sum_up = mysqli_num_rows($result_sum_up); 
$prices = [];  //Create the prices array 
while($row_sum_up = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sum_up,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $prices[] = $row_sum_up['price']; //This pushes every price into the array
}
```

1. Make use of join/implode - [PHP.net join function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join)

   echo '['.join(',',$prices).']';
2. You could use json_encode function [PHP.net json_encode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode)

   echo json_encode($prices);

Comment: _Side notes:_ You can discard the `$count_sum_up` altogether since it isn't actually used. You should also remove the suggestion about `implode()` and just stick to the `json_encode()`.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. The count has been left in my example cause the OP has it in his code, we don't actually know if the code that comes after would make use of it or not. The json_encode() function is only available if you have the JSON extension installed (which is now active by default but not in older PHP versions) thus IMHO the example with implode/join is still useful.